# Need help storing deck of cards in a list and giving them their respective integer values?

Tags: python, list

I'm fairly new at coding and I'm making a game in which the user plays a random card drawing game against the computer. The goal is to reach 50 points first and you reach that by drawing the cards. For example, a 2 of Clubs should have a value of 2 and a King of Hearts should have a value of 13. However, I'm struggling with finding a way to assign these integer values to each card in the deck, while keeping it stored in the list. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

```
# Useful Definitions
user_score = 0
computer_score = 0
type = "user"
winner = "none"
import random
card_list = ['1 Clubs', '2 Clubs', '3 Clubs', '4 Clubs', '5 Clubs', '6 Clubs', '7 Clubs', '8 Clubs', '9 Clubs', '10 Clubs', '11 Clubs', '12 Clubs', '13 Clubs', '1 Hearts', '2 Hearts', '3 Hearts', '4 Hearts', '5 Hearts', '6 Hearts', '7 Hearts', '8 Hearts', '9 Hearts', '10 Hearts', '11 Hearts', '12 Hearts', '13 Hearts', '1 Spades', '2 Spades', '3 Spades', '4 Spades', '5 Spades', '6 Spades', '7 Spades', '8 Spades', '9 Spades', '10 Spades', '11 Spades', '12 Spades', '13 Spades', '1 Diamonds', '2 Diamonds', '3 Diamonds', '4 Diamonds', '5 Diamonds', '6 Diamonds', '7 Diamonds', '8 Diamonds', '9 Diamonds', '10 Diamonds', '11 Diamonds', '12 Diamonds', '13 Diamonds',]



# Introduction code
print("Hello, Welcome to the Pig Card Game!")
user_name = input("What's your name? ")
cont = input("Press enter to learn how to play, " + user_name)
print()
print("***************************************************************")
print()


#Main Menu Function
def main_menu(name):
    print()
    print("What would you like to do, " + user_name + "?")
    print("1. Learn the Rules of Pig")
    print("2. Play!!")
    print("3. Exit.")
    choice = input("Enter your selection: ")
    print("*****************************************************")
    print()
    return choice
    

# Instructions
def game_rules():
    
    print("1. In the game, you will play against the computer in a luck-based")
    print("card game.")
    print("2. During your turn, you will draw a random card from  standard")
    print("deck of cards.")
    print("Each card is worth its standard numerical value - A 2 is worth 2")
    print("points and a King is worth 13 Points")
    print("3. You may choose to continue your turn as long as you want, by")
    print("drawing more random cards and adding those to your point total.")
    print("4. However, if at any point in your turn, you draw an ace or a")
    print("jack of any suit, you will lose all of your points collected in")
    print("your turn and your turn will end.")
    print("5. The first player to reach a score of 50 points loses.")
    print()
    cont = input("Press enter to go back to the main menu")
    print()
    print("***************************************************************")
    print()


def game_turn(type):
    
    while user_score != 50 and computer_score != 50:
        global random_drawn_card
        if type == "user":
            user_turn_score = 0
            cont = input("It is your turn, " + user_name + ". Press enter to draw a random card.")
            random_drawn_card = random.choice(card_list)
            print("Your card: " + random_drawn_card)
            card_list.remove(random_drawn_card)
            if random_drawn_card == "1 Clubs" or random_drawn_card == "1 Hearts" or random_drawn_card == "1 Diamonds" or random_drawn_card == "1 Spades" or random_drawn_card == "11 Clubs" or random_drawn_card == "11 Hearts" or random_drawn_card == "11 Diamonds" or random_drawn_card == "11 Spades":
                user_turn_score = 0
                print("You drew an Ace or a Jack. You will not gain any points this turn.")
                type = "computer"
            else:
                user_turn_score = user_turn_score
                print("Your total score: " + str(user_score))
                turn_type = input("Do you want to continue your turn? (Y/N) ")
                if turn_type == "Y":
                    type = "user"
                else:
                    type = "computer"
            print()
            print("***************************************************************")
            print()
        
        elif type == "computer":
            computer_turn_score = 0
            print("It is the computer's turn. Drawing a random card.")
            random_drawn_card = random.choice(card_list)
            print("Computer's Card: " + random_drawn_card)
            card_list.remove(random_drawn_card)
            if random_drawn_card == "A Clubs" or random_drawn_card == "A Hearts" or random_drawn_card == "A Diamonds" or random_drawn_card == "A Spades" or random_drawn_card == "J Clubs" or random_drawn_card == "J Hearts" or random_drawn_card == "J Diamonds" or random_drawn_card == "J Spades":
                computer_turn_score = 0
                print("The computer drew an Ace or a Jack. It will not gain any points this turn.")
                type = "user"
            else:
                computer_turn_score = computer_turn_score
                print("Computer's total score: " + str(computer_score))
                computer_turn = random.randint(1,2)
                if computer_turn == 1:
                    type = "computer"
                    print("The computer will take another turn.")
                else:
                    type = "user"
                    print("The computer will not take another turn.")
            print()
            print("***************************************************************")
            print()


main_choice = main_menu(user_name)

#Loop that encompasses the entire game that determines if user goes to rules, plays, or leaves
while main_choice != "3":
    
    if main_choice == "1":
        game_rules()
    elif main_choice == "2":
        user = game_turn(type)
    else:
        print("Invalid Selection. Choose a number between 1 and 3.")

    main_choice = main_menu(user_name)
    
    
#Outro message to user
print("Thanks for playing, " + user_name + ". See you next time!")
```

Comment: each card could be a `dict` with the card and a value. Each card could be mapped to a dict. You could split the card string and set the value to be the first part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a `Card` class. This might be new if you are new to programming, but it's not super complicated and has a lot of advantages — it makes your code more readable and lets you define data and behavior in one structure. I've added some comments under the methods to help. A class will let you make individual instances of the cards that encapsulate date like the value and range. Additionally you can add behavior, like what happens when you print a card or add two cards together. Here's a rough start:

```
class Card:
    suits = {'c': '♣','h': '♥','s': '♠','d': '♦'}
    faces = {
        1: 'Ace',
        11: 'Jack',
        12: 'Queen',
        13: 'King'
    }
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        '''Called when you create a new card. For example `Card(10, 'h')`'''
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
    
    def __repr__(self):
        '''A string representation of the card'''
        face = self.faces.get(self.rank, self.rank)
        return f'{face}{self.suits[self.suit]}'
        
    def __add__(self, other):
        '''What happens when you add a card to another (or to an integer)
           For example this_card + someOther_card'''
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return self.rank + other
        return self.rank + other.rank

    def __radd__(self, other):
        '''What happens when you add another or integer to this card. 
           For example `someOther_card + this_card`'''
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return other + self.rank
        return self.rank + other.rank
```

Now you can use is. Make a new card:

```
acard = Card(10, 'h')
print(acard)
# 10♥
acard.rank
# 10
```

Make a full deck:

```
sorted_deck = [Card(n, s) for s in Card.suits for n in range(1, 14)]

len(sorted_deck)
# 52
sorted_deck[10: 15] # take a slice of the deck
# [Jack♣, Queen♣, King♣, Ace♥, 2♥]
```

Shuffle it and draw a hand of 7:

```
from random import shuffle

shuffle(sorted_deck)
sorted_deck[0:7]
# [4♣, 3♣, 10♥, 8♥, 7♦, 3♥, 2♠]
```

Sum the values of some card:

```
cards = [Card(9, 'h'), Card(11, 'd'), Card(1, 's')]

sum(cards)
# 21
```

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful. One more thing, do you know how to assign a variable to the value on a singular random card? In my program, a random card is drawn and removed from the deck, and then its value is added to the total score of the user or computer. Is there a way to do something similar to what you did to find the sum of the values of some cards such as: value = [Card(random_drawn_card)] without getting an error message? Also, if classifying it, is the "sorted deck" classified as a list? I just need to make sure that I use a list in this code.

Comment: @Clare yes `sorted_deck` is a list. The syntax used to create it (with the `[...]`) is a list comprehension. I'm not quite sure what you are asking about the variable. You can get a random card from the list using the Random module. `from random import choice;` then `some_val = choice(sorted_deck)`. You can also make a random card by passing random values in the `Card()` `some_var = Card(randint(1,13), choice('dhsc'))` which gets a random number and a random letter from the the suits. (`randint` also needs to be imported from random).

Comment: Sorry, I think I phrased my question the wrong way. In my code, I draw a random card from the list. I want to have a value attached to each card (ex. 2 clubs has a value of 2 and King hearts has value of 13), because these values make up the user and computer's points. Is there a way I can access the value of that random card (random_drawn_card) so that I can use it to add onto the scores? I tried to do something like:  value = sorted_deck(int[(random_drawn_card.split()[0])])                                    
user_turn_score = user_turn_score + value    but got an error message.

Comment: Oh, if the cards are instances of the class Card described above, you can get the value using `acard.rank` where `arcard` is the variable. That's because we saved that value to the instance in the `__init__()` function. The way the class is written you can also jus add cards: `some_card + 10` or `some_card + other_card`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. One is to store each card as something other than a string. For instance, you could have each card as being a sublist containing it suit and value. Or you could represent it as a dictionary. Another option would be to find a way of extracting the value from the string. Since you're putting a space between the value and the suit, doing `int(card.split()[0])` will split on the space (space is the default character to split on), take the first part (the part before the space), and then turn it into an integer.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to map such things is with Python's standard translation mechanism: the `dict`.

```
card_value = {
    'A': 1,
    '2': 2,
    '3': 3,
    ...
    '10': 10,
    'J': 11,
    'Q': 12,
    'K': 13
}
```

To convert, simply split the card, grab the rank (element 0), and use the dict to get the value:

```
value = card_value[ card.split()[0] ]
```

For instance, if the `card` is "5 Clubs", then `card.split()` is `["5", "Clubs"]`;  `card_value["5"]` is `5`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a dictionary for that procedure

Something like this:

```
suits = {
    0: 'Clubs',
    1: 'Diamonds',
    2: 'Hearts',
    3: 'Spades'
}

cards = {
    0: 'Ace',
    1: '2',
    2: '3',
    3: '4',
    4: '5',
    5: '6',
    6: '7',
    7: '8',
    8: '9',
    9: '10',
    10: 'Jack',
    11: 'Queen',
    12: 'King'
}

table = {}

for i in suits:
    for j in cards:
        table[cards[j]+'_' + suits[i]] = j+1


print(table)
```

Out:

```
{'Ace_Clubs': 1, '2_Clubs': 2, '3_Clubs': 3, '4_Clubs': 4, '5_Clubs': 5, '6_Clubs': 6, '7_Clubs': 7, '8_Clubs': 8, '9_Clubs': 9, '10_Clubs': 10, 'Jack_Clubs': 11, 'Queen_Clubs': 12, 'King_Clubs': 13, 'Ace_Diamonds': 1, '2_Diamonds': 2, '3_Diamonds': 3, '4_Diamonds': 4, '5_Diamonds': 5, '6_Diamonds': 6, '7_Diamonds': 7, '8_Diamonds': 8, '9_Diamonds': 9, '10_Diamonds': 10, 'Jack_Diamonds': 11, 'Queen_Diamonds': 12, 'King_Diamonds': 13, 'Ace_Hearts': 1, '2_Hearts': 2, '3_Hearts': 3, '4_Hearts': 4, '5_Hearts': 5, '6_Hearts': 6, '7_Hearts': 7, '8_Hearts': 8, '9_Hearts': 9, '10_Hearts': 10, 'Jack_Hearts': 11, 'Queen_Hearts': 12, 'King_Hearts': 13, 'Ace_Spades': 1, '2_Spades': 2, '3_Spades': 3, '4_Spades': 4, '5_Spades': 5, '6_Spades': 6, '7_Spades': 7, '8_Spades': 8, '9_Spades': 9, '10_Spades': 10, 'Jack_Spades': 11, 'Queen_Spades': 12, 'King_Spades': 13}
```

Where the key is your card and the value its score